# How to iterate over array with forEach and update element in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My user model has this shape:

```
{
name: "Some User",
events: [{title: "String", count: 1}]
}
```

Each time the user loads my application, I'd like to loop over every array and perform calculations. For simplicity, in this code snippet, I'm trying to set the count value to 10000. However, I'm getting this error:

user.events.updateOne is not a function.

Here is my endpoint code:

```
        user.events.forEach((e, i) => {
          user.events.updateOne(
            { _id: e._id.toString() },
            { $set: { count: 10000 } }
          );
        });
      });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use user.updateOne() query

Answer (score 0):

The `events` property of your `user` object is an array. And there is not such function `upadteOne()` for your array. If you want to modify your event, you could use the `map`function on your event to change their values. ex:

```
user.events.map((event) => {
    // we change something in the event.
    event.title +=  ""
    event.count = 10000
    // we are returning the updated event, so it can be modified in the original array
    return event;
});
// now that each event has been modified, we can save the user.
user.updateOne();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this information. I'm having trouble getting the changes reflected in my database. Here's my code: 

`User.findOne({ _id: id }, function(err, user) {
        user.events.map((e, i) => {
          e.count = 1000;
          return e;
        });

        User.updateOne();
      });`

Comment: It only worked with user.save() not user.updateOne()

Answer (score 0):

```
user.events.map((event) => {
    event.title =  event.title;
    event.count = 10000
    return event;
});

user.update({_id: user._id }, { $set: { events: user.events });
```

Comment: Why does map work in this case? You are not using the returned array.

Comment: here using the returned array